# Minecraft glitching the display on Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am having a problem with the display when I run Minecraft. Half of the screen flickers diagonally, but it only happens when I look in certain directions.

Also, I cannot play Minecraft looking at the sky the whole time. Any idea what might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I cannot play Minecraft looking at the sky the whole time.'?

Do you mean that you cannot play it while facing straight up at the sky, or that all you see is the sky?

Comment: @Lemmings He means looking at the sky is the only direction that works, but the game won't be much fun if that's the only way he can look. (I have this problem on one of my computers also.)

Comment: Screenshots and system specs (both hardware and OS) would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a while, I installed the mod [Optifine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-11-optifine-hd-d4-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af/), and it helped a lot. If that doesn't help, try messing with the graphics settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your graphics driver. And also make sure your version of mc is up to date. If that doesn't help, you should also try asking on the mc forum.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured for me on an Optimus system when using the Intel card. This did not happen while using the nVidia card. If your system is an optimus system (it has both a nvidia card and an Intel card), try installing [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and using that to force Minecraft to run on the nVidia card.